# Wrong index when appending maximum values from arrays into another array

Tags: python, arrays, function, indexing, max

I have a problem with the output of this code :

```
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
a1=15.8
a2=18.3
a3=0.714
a4=23.2

def bindingenergy():
    maxvalues=[]
    for Z in range (1,106):
        values=[]
        for A in range (Z, 3*Z+1):
            if A%2==1:
                a5=0
            elif A%2==0 and Z%2==0:
                a5=12
            else:
                a5=-12
            B=a1*A-a2*A**(2/3)-a3*((Z**2)/A**(1/3))-a4*(((A-2*Z)**2)/A)+(a5/A**(1/2))
            C=B/A
            values.append(C)
            D=max(values)
            E=values.index(D) 
        maxvalues.append(D)    
        print ("the most stable nucleon for an atomic number",Z," has a nucleon number",E+Z,"and its binding energy per nucleon is",D,"mEv")
    F=max(maxvalues)
    G=maxvalues.index(F)
    print ("the most stable nucleon of them all has an atomic number",G,"and its binding energy per nucleon is",F,"mEv")
```

As you can see, this function runs a calculation for two cycles, before it moves onto the next number Z, it stores all results for that one particular number Z and multiple A's(range (Z, 3*Z+1)) into an array, then finds the index of the maximum value and prints it for that particular number Z, no problem here.

But I wanted to find the number Z with the biggest value of them all. So I made it repeat the process for the maximums for each number Z.

When I run the function, it prints all the numbers Z, its most stable isotope(number E+Z) and the appropriate binding energy a.k.a the maximum value of the calculations for that particular number Z and the numbers A in range(Z,3*Z+1). As the last line, it should print out the number Z that has the biggest value of all numbers Z. The program says that that number is Z=27. However when I look into the values printed for all numbers Z, I see that the answer should be Z=28. Why doesn't it print the correct number Z in the last line of the output?

Comment: Because you're equating the maximum value to the last value observed in this loop: for A in range (Z, 3*Z+1). Instead: maxvalues.append(max(values))

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
A simple `print` to trace the values you use would show the problem quickly.  Also, this is *not* the expected [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Ghoti I don't understand how I'm equating the maximum value to the last value :D I have just run a print of all the values for one particular number Z and the maximum values that the program prints are not in the last place in their respective loop. Anyway I changed the line maxvalues.append(D) to your line and it didn't help.

Comment: @Prune Did the test cases part, I think the problem has something to do with the way that Python is indexing values in arrays, but I don't get how it gets messed up when doing the second indexing. When I print the values for one number Z, the index matches the max value. But when I print the maximums, it doesn't match.

Comment: When you've posted your MCVE, we can take a look.

Comment: @Johnny Sorry, you're right, my earlier feedback was unhelpful. Your indexing problem is due to python counts starting at zero. Your provided range begins at 1, so all you need to do is add 1 to the G value to correct. This applies to all indexes you've done. You'll also want to add one to the E value.

Comment: @Ghoti Yeah, that was the problem. I knew the indexing started at 0, but I didn't realize that I am actually taking the number Z from 1, so the corresponding max value will have an index 0, therefore all the numbers differ by 1. Thanks a lot for your help Ghoti.